# Laravel HTTP ERROR 500 linux

Tags: laravel, linux, http

Sou um noob completo em Linux, estava trabalhando normalmente, e o Linux instalou algumas atualizações que de repente ao invés de mostrar a tela de erro do Laravel, recebo a tela.

`HTTP ERROR 500`

No meio disso eu estava usando o comando git stash sem saber exatamente como, mas não sei ao certo o que pode ter causado esse problema.

Comment: o **APP_DEBUG** no seu arquivo .env está true? se sim troque para false.

Comment: Erro 500 é um erro interno , pode existir um erro no seu código Laravel, você pode colocar foto ou algum assim para poder ajudar melhor. Uma dica olha no console do teu navegador ele pode te dar alguma dica . Git stash é a grosso modo é remover todas as alterações feitas e voltar para o estado do seu commit . Olha na documentação do git para ter mais informações.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi com o comando sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/pmts/storage/logs

provavelmente a atualização revogou alguns acesso do a pagina de logs do laravel, assim ele não exibia o erro